# Is there a way to modify foreach loop variable?

Tags: perl, variables, loops, foreach, readonly

The following code gives an error message:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

foreach my $var (0, 1, 2){
    $var += 2;
    print "$var\n";
}
```

`Modification of a read-only value attempted at test.pl line 4.`

Is there any way to modify `$var`? (I'm just asking out of curiosity; I was actually quite surprised to see this error message.)

Comment: Why would you *want* to modify the loop variable? It sounds like a way to make the loop behaviour unpredictable. *But maybe that's what you want?*

Comment: It doesn't make the loop behaviour unpredictable in the sense that it doesn't disturb the iterator. The result may be unexpected, but it's completely predictable.

Comment: +1 for curiosity and the desire to understand error messages, even if you have already found a workaround :-).

Answer (score 13):

In a `foreach $var (@list)` construct, `$var` becomes aliased to the elements of the loop, in the sense that the memory address of `$var` would be the same address as an element of `@list`. So your example code attempts to modify read-only values, and you get the error message.

This little script will demonstrate what is going on in the `foreach` construct:

```
my @a = (0,1,2);
print "Before: @a\n";
foreach my $var (@a) {
  $var += 2;
}
print "After:  @a\n";

Before: 0 1 2
After:  2 3 4
```

**Additional info:** [This item](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) from [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) is easy to gloss over but gives the whole scoop:

> Foreach loops
>
> ...
>
> If any element of LIST is an lvalue,
>   you can modify it by modifying VAR
>   inside the loop.  Conversely, if any
>   element of LIST is NOT an lvalue, any
>   attempt to modify that element will
>   fail.  In other words, the "foreach"
>   loop index variable is an implicit
>   alias for each item in the list that
>   you're looping over.

Answer (score 5):

Perl is complaining about the values which are constants, not the loop variable. The readonly value it's complaining about is your `0` because `$var` is an alias to it, and it's not stored in a variable (which is something that you can change). If you loop over an array or a list of variables, you don't have that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Figuring out why the following does not result in the same message will go a long way toward improving your understanding of why the message is emitted in the first place:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for my $x ( @{[ 0, 1, 2 ]} ) {
    $x += 2;
    print $x, "\n";
}
```